# Extension of a vector field $X:A\subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-topology, dynamical-systems

Define $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2;\ x\leq 0\ \text{or }  y \leq x^2 \}$ ( a representation of $A$ can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9QWB.jpg).)

Let $X:A\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a smooth function such that $X(\partial A) = (1,0)$ and $\tau:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ a diffeomorphism satisfying $\tau'>0$ and $\tau(0) = 0$.

> **My Question:** Is it possible to extend $X$ to a fuction $\tilde{X}:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$, such that the orbit of $\tilde{X}$ startig at the point $(0,y)$ (with $y>0$) also passes through the point$(\tau(y),\tau(y)^2)$.

Just for the records, I am searching for a smooth planar vector field $\tilde{X}$, such that $\left. \tilde{X}\right|_{A} = X$ and $\forall$ $y>0$ the solution $\varphi_y$ of the ODE
\begin{align*}\dot{x} &= \tilde
{X}(x) \\
x(0) &= (0,y).\\
\end{align*}
satisfy the condition, $\exists$  $t_y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi_y(t_y) = \left(\tau(y),\tau(y)^2 \right)$.

---

If the result is true just in the neighborhood of the origin it is good enough for me. I don't have any ideas on how to tackle this problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Don't you mean $\varphi_y(t_y)=(\tau(y)^2,\tau(y))$ ? So that $\varphi_y(t_y) \in \partial A$

Comment: Is it wrong the way that I defined $A$? I would like to define $A$ as the image.

Comment: it seems that the $A$ you drew is $\{ (x,y) ; x \leqslant 0 \text{or} y \leqslant x^2 \}$

Comment: You are right, I changed. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. But my "proof" is just a drawing : you draw a smooth curve $\gamma_1$ from $(0,1)$ to $(\tau(1),\tau(1)^2$ such that $\gamma_1(0,1)=\gamma_1(\tau(1),\tau(1)^2)=(1,0)$ and you take a deformation of this to get a path $\gamma_y$ from $(0,y)$ to $(\tau(y),\tau(y)^2)$ as you want it to be. Finally contruct $\tilde{X}$ from the $\gamma_y$'s.

Comment: How do you construct $\tilde{X}$ having this family of curves?

Comment: You can construct the curves so that $\cup_{y>0} \mathrm{im} (\gamma_y) = \{ (x,y) ; x \geqslant 0 \text{ and } y \geqslant x^2 \}$ and for $y \neq y^\prime$, $\mathrm{im} (\gamma_y) \cap \mathrm{im} (\gamma_{y^\prime}) = \emptyset$.
So for $(x,y)$ with $x \geqslant 0$ and $y \geqslant x^2$, there is a unique $y_0$ such that $(x,y) \in \mathrm{im} (\gamma_{y_0})$. Define $\tilde{X}(x,y)$ to be $\gamma_{y_0}^\prime(x,y)$ (the derivative of $\gamma_{y_0}$ at $(x,y)$)

Comment: My final question, do you know how to construct this deformation? I'm not sure if there is a way to preserve $\gamma_y'(0,y) = \gamma_y' (\tau(y),\tau(y)^2) = (1,0)$ (I liked your notation).